# HERE Android SDK Turn by turn instruction

Tags: android, sdk, navigation, here-api, turn

I am using HERE Android SDK to perform turn by turn navigation project. But I do not get the result similar to image.

[image]

I hava this code to get the current manauver

```
private NavigationManager.NewInstructionEventListener newInstructionEventListener = new NavigationManager.NewInstructionEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onNewInstructionEvent() {
        Maneuver maneuver = navigationManager.getNextManeuver();

        if (maneuver != null) {
            if (maneuver.getAction() == Maneuver.Action.END) {

            }

            tvManeuver.setText(navigationManager.getNextManeuver().getTurn().name() + " " + maneuver.getIcon().value());
            ivTitle.setImageBitmap(maneuver.getNextRoadImage().getBitmap());
            tvStreet.setText(maneuver.getRoadName());
            tvMeters.setText("durante " + maneuver.getDistanceFromPreviousManeuver() + " m");

            if (maneuver.getDistanceToNextManeuver() == 0) {
                tvMeters.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            } else {
                tvMeters.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }
        }
    }
};
```

But I do not get the correct text of the maneuver. For example "Turn right at the next corner" and the and the corresponding arrow icon to put inside IMAGEVIEW.

can anybody help me?

Regards.

Comment: Can u guide me to get the list of all Maneuver available for the current route?

Comment: the above code gives the information of next maneuver only.i just wanted to get the maneuver information i n the form of list.can anyone guide me here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the image you provided is from HERE Maps available on Google Store which is a custom implementation using the HERE SDK.

The instruction you can get from Maneuver  , check documentation 
https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-routing-maneuver.html#topic-apiref__getinstruction-void

Icon should also be retrieved from getIcon() , which gives an enumeration and you will need to create images for possible enumerations in the icon , check documentation
https://developer.here.com/mobile-sdks/documentation/android-hybrid-plus/topics_api_nlp_hybrid_plus/com-here-android-mpa-routing-maneuver-icon.html#topic-apiref

Comment: Hello, Can you please let me know how to convert enumerations to icon ?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the list of maneuvers, you can't get it on the NewInstructionEvent. 
Since you are already in navigation you should already have your route object. On the route object you can just call getManeuvers(). That will give you all the list of maneuvers for the current route.

You can also refer to their UI Kit https://developer.here.com/blog/build-beautiful-interfaces-with-the-here-mobile-sdk-ui-kit-for-android-and-ios.

Hope this helps. I know this is an older thread.

Answer (score 0):

HERE SDK Premium does not provide Maneuver Instructions pre- start of Navigation nor can you get a list of Maneuver Instructions at any point.

You however could get a list of Maneuver Instructions using the HERE Routing API.

https://developer.here.com/documentation/routing-api/dev_guide/topics/use-cases/actions.html

One more way is to get Instructions through the AudioPlayerDelegate.PlayText callback.